# linux whiptail with degree symbol

Tags: linux, unicode, whiptail

I want to display a message which contains the degree symbol using whiptail. I tried these, but none seem to work:

```
whiptail --title "Weather Info" --msgbox '\N{U+00B0}'  17 60 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
whiptail --title "Weather Info" --msgbox "\N{U+00B0}"  17 60 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
whiptail --title "Weather Info" --msgbox "\xc2\xb0"  17 60 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
whiptail --title "Weather Info" --msgbox '\xc2\xb0'  17 60 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

Is it impossible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Neither whiptail nor bash provides help with this case of escaping.  You can verify this using bash's built-in echo.

If you use the literal degree symbol without any help from escaping, *that* works:

```
whiptail --title "Weather Info" --msgbox '°'  17 60 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

Comment: Actually Bash 4 supports `printf '\u00B0'` if you want your script to be pure ASCII for portability and robustness. You'll need a process substitution like `--msgbox "$(printf '\uB0')"` which isn't IMHO very elegat, though.

Comment: I see (half a point for portability, since it still is a bash-specific feature).

Comment: Hello, Sorry I haven't been online for a couple of weeks. I tried out the printf way but it doesn't work. The degree symbol appears as a pattersn, the size of the block cursor in terminal. Here is a link to the output: http://ibin.co/23nV4khMxKwV.

Comment: I also tried it by directly copy/pasting the degree symbol. This partly works. It does display the symbol correctly. However, the whiptail border gets skewed, as if the symbol as contains a backspace character which it is interpreting. Image here: http://ibin.co/23nWLQnF7JDR

Comment: In your screenshot, whiptail is counting bytes rather than characters when it computes the width of the string.  (However both whiptail and dialog get it right in my Debian6 development machine).